# How to transform square to isosceles trapezoid?

Tags: css, matrix, transform

I have a 200*200 px div, and I would like to transform it to an [Isosceles Trapezoid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IsoscelesTrapezoid.html), where the base, and the height is still 200px, but the a side should be 100px.

[image: Isosceles Trapezoid]
<sub>(from MathWorld - A Wolfram Web Resource: [wolfram.com](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/IsoscelesTrapezoid_900.gif))</sub>

The original square is 200*200px. The `h`, and `b` sides should be booth 200px, and the `a` side should be 100px.

I tried to combine skew, scale, and rotate, but I have no idea, how to manage it. Maybe I should use the `transform: matrix(n,n,n,n,n,n)` function, but I don't really know, how to make a transformation matrix for this project.

Comment: http://www.htmllion.com/css3-transform-tool.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like this

```
div.transform {
  perspective: 400px;
  transform-origin: 100px 200px;

  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;

  display: inline-block;
  background-color: magenta;
}
div.transform img {
  transform-origin: 100px 200px 0;
  transform: rotate3d(1,0,0, 45deg) scale3d(1, 1.89, 1);
}
```

See [Codepen](http://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/Hgifr/)

Comment: Thank you, it works. But how do I calculate the rotate, and scale values, to make the top side 100px length?